# ASP.NET [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied] Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I test it in Visuall Studio by pressing F5 and it's working fine and I can able to login the webpage and sql query process working nicely.  Also note that my SQL server is active over internet which can be accessed using IP address.

But when I publish my ASP.Net Website in myasp.net hosting service provider and and I am getting the login screen working nicely.  But the problem is when I click login button I am getting the below error which is not occurring while testing in VS.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access is denied Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is
>   denied
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +1005
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +799
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +726
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +85
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +449
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +108
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +942
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +17
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +139
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +367    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +129
>   UserLogin_VB.Login.ValidateUser(Object sender, EventArgs e) +220
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs
>   e) +109    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +119
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs
>   e) +75    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +120
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +166
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +31    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3450

Comment: Check your Connection String, if its correct then it must be a firewall issue.

Comment: I don't think your provider will allow you to access a private sql like that. If that's the case you'll need to use a sql that is hosted and supported by your asp.net provider.

Comment: @Dr. Stitch 4, The SQL connection part and firewalls are perfect since my Windows based exe's are working fine with the same connection string in different locations by way of connecting the sql server by ip address.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Sixthsense, so your windows exes are also located in the server which your website is deploy?

Comment: @Asken, that may be the reason I think I will check it since the hosting provider is providing sql server also but I don't want my data to reside in someone's server.  I am confused about how they can stop the connection to my sql server since everything is in my ASP.Net published files.

Comment: @Dr. Stitch, That is not related with this ASP.Net project that are all standalone exe's which can run on any system from any folder which needs only internet connection to connect with sql server.

Comment: @Sixthsense It's really easy for them to not allow it. By default you're normally not allowed to access any outside resources on a hosted web unless you actually request it to be accessible. In many cases it's not even an option to not use any of the servers supported by the provider.

Answer (score 0):

> **Asken Quote:**
>
> I don't think your provider will allow you to access a private sql
>   like that. If that's the case you'll need to use a sql that is hosted
>   and supported by your asp.net provider.

**@Asken**
You're right... I received the following reply from the myasp.net customer support.

> Dear Customer,
>
> Sorry, for performance reasons, we don't allow our customer to connect
>   to remote database server. We suggest you simply make a backup of your
>   database and restore it to our server to test your application. You’ll
>   see a much faster performance and reliability using this method.
>
> However, if you must connect to a remote database server, please
>   consider upgrading to our Premium Plan or Semi Dedi Plan. Once you
>   upgrade to these hosting plans, you can enable any ports your want in
>   your Control Panel -> Security Manager -> Outgoing Port Manager.
>
> And don't worry, we provide a 60 days FULL Money Back for all of our
>   plans.
>
> Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

check you are using correct login credential in web-config file, if yes then please give a full access to network group

Comment: The web is hosted on a remote location and the server somewhere else. They're not on the same network.

Comment: This should be a comment, it does not answer the question